# C Language- freeing memory after using strtok to build char**

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

and sorry for the title I couldn't think of a better way to phrase it.

so I have a C assignment working with `fork` and `exec`.

I have three programs called `ps`, `echo` and `history` all of them take different arguments. The final program is called `shell` and it takes in commands from `stdin` and calls for `exec` upon taking a proper command.

example:

```
ps -a 

echo Hello World

history 1.txt
```

once it reads a line and find it's a valid command it makes a child process and calls for `exec`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const int MAX_LINE = 100;

const char *HISTORY = "./history";
const char *PS = "./ps";
const char *ECHO = "./echo";

void call_cmd(int cmd, char *const argv[]);

/* main function */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE * out;
    char line[MAX_LINE], line_print[MAX_LINE], seps[] = " \n", rm[80];
    char *first, *tmp, ** params;
    pid_t pid;
    int cmd = -1, i = 0,j= 0;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid arguments");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    out = fopen(argv[1],"w");
    if (out == NULL)
    {
        perror("Couldn't open file to write");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin) != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(line_print,line);
        params = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*));
        tmp = strtok(line,seps);
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            if(i != 0)
            params = (char**) realloc(params,sizeof(char*) * (i + 1));
            params[i] = tmp;
            j++;
            tmp = strtok(NULL,seps);
            i++;
        }
        first = params[0];
        if (strcmp("exit",first) == 0)
        {
            sprintf(rm,"rm %s",argv[1]);
            system(rm);
                        exit(0);
        }
        if(strcmp("echo",first) == 0)
            cmd = 0;
        if(strcmp("history",first) == 0)
            cmd = 1;
        if(strcmp("ps",first) == 0)
            cmd = 2;
        if(cmd == -1){
            perror("\nInvalid Command\n");
        }
        if(cmd >= 0)
        {
            fprintf(out,"%s",line_print);
            pid = fork();
            if (pid == -1)
            {
                perror("Error Creating Child");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            if(pid == 0)
            {
                call_cmd(cmd,params);
                exit(0);
            }
        }   
        for (i = 0; i < j ; i++)
             free(params[i]);
        free(params);   
        i = j = 0;
        cmd = -1;
    }
    fclose(out);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void call_cmd(int cmd, char *const argv[])
{
    switch(cmd)
    {
        case 0:
            execv(ECHO, argv);
            break;
        case 1:

            execv(HISTORY, argv);
            break;
        default:
            execv(PS, argv);
            break;
    }
}
```

that is my code so far, it behaves in a weird way causing segmentation faults,
I'm pretty sure it's because of the way I split the parameters and free them.

example output:

```
*** Error in `./shell': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffe58f1a630 ***
Parent Id: 1928
Aborted (core dumped)
```

so I keep editing the for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < j ; i++)
         free(params[i]);
```

all that does is just jump from double free to segmentation faults or I write a command like ps or history and it does nothing, so I must be doing something but I'm truly lost been trying to fix it for two days with, so if you see what I did wrong please point it out.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with debug symbols and executing under GDB or something similar?  This will tell you precisely where the problem is.

Comment: yes I did, each time I fix something something else pops up, so something is wrong with the way I built the code or I'm using strtok in a wrong way.

Comment: yes but I'm using realloc when needed

Comment: `cmd = -1` should be set *inside* the `while(fgets(...))` loop.

Comment: it is inside the loop at the end

Comment: Don't do that. Set the variables first, same with `i` and `j`.

Comment: all of them are defined at the top of the main function, then they are reset and the end of the while loop

Comment: It's poor practice, makes the code hard to follow, makes you set them twice, and requires the code to be read bottom-up.

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't execv  need the last element in the parameter list to be NULL, so that it can determine the end of the array?

Comment: @WeatherVane ok will do so
user3121023 so the for loop it self isn't needed, I tried without it leads codes not working.
zeyorama if that's true then that will explain why some lines just don't work so I have to set the last member of params to null. I will test it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add

```
params[0] = NULL;
```

right after the initial malloc (or use calloc) otherwise you'll be using an unitialized pointer if the line is empty. Then at the end

```
free(params);
```

you don't need to free any of params[i] since those are pointers into the local line[] buffer.

Comment: yes I will test it out right now, and give feedback

Comment: it appears to be working thank you, I applied your fix and what @zeyorama mentioned

Answer (score 4):

`strtok` parses a string *in-place* so you should not free the individual results. They are portions of the original string. You can use the POSIX function `strdup` to make copies that can be free'd, and will persist beyond the life of the original buffer contents.